# Error al obtener datos mediante Python

Tags: python, base-de-datos

Hola estoy tratando de obtener datos desde PESDB y colocarlos en mi base de datos pero a la hora de obtenerlos arroja error

Error que da:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pao\Desktop\pesDB-master\pesdb.py", line 22, in <module>
    gi.getplayerinfo(players_urlid[i][2:], players_name[i], data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
  File "C:\Users\Pao\Desktop\pesDB-master\GetInfo.py", line 72, in getplayerinfo
    get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas)
  File "C:\Users\Pao\Desktop\pesDB-master\GetInfo.py", line 23, in get_abilities
    level_datas[data_name[i]] = abilities[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Las líneas son las siguientes:
pesdb.py Linea 22

```
gi.getplayerinfo(players_urlid[i][2:], players_name[i], data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
for i in range(len(players_urlid)):
    gi.getplayerinfo(players_urlid[i][2:], players_name[i], data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    
    print(playing_style,'\n',player_skills,'\n',com_playing_styles)
    
    db_o.insert_baseinfo(cur, players_num[i], players_urlid[i], players_name[i], other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    #for table_name, leval_data in level_datas.items():
    #   db_o.insert_abilitys(cur,   , players_num[i], players_name[i], leval_data)
    print('--------------------------------------')
```

Error en la linea 72 archivo GetInfo.py

```
get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas)
```

[image: error3]

```
def getplayerinfo(player_urlid, player_name, data_name, level_datas, other_info, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles):
    """根据球员id获得球员信息"""
    print('recuperando:',player_name,'Información')
    html = urlopen('http://pesdb.net/pes2021/' + player_urlid)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print('Procesando')
    del other_info[:], playing_style[:], player_skills[:], com_playing_styles[:]
    #获取能力值
    get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas)
    
    #获取风格信息
    get_styles(bsObj, playing_style, player_skills, com_playing_styles)
    
    #获取其他基本信息
    get_oterinfo(bsObj, other_info)
    print('¡Obtenido con éxito!')
```

Error en la linea 23 archivo GetInfo.py

```
level_datas[data_name[i]] = abilities[i]
```

[image: error2]

```
def get_abilities(bsObj, data_name, level_datas):
    abilities = bsObj.find('script',text=re.compile('abilities.*')).get_text()
    abilities = abilities[14:-3].replace(',[','').split("]")
    for i in range(len(data_name)):
        level_datas[data_name[i]] = abilities[i]
```

Me obtiene datos de un jugador y arroja ese error dejo captura
[image: Error1]

data_name es un array que esta compuesto de la sig forma

```
data_name = ['Capacidad ofensiva','Posesion de la pelota','Regatear','Pase de tierra','Pase de aire','Disparo','Establecer bola'                ,'radian','Cabecera','Habilidad defensiva','Agarra la pelota','Fuerza del pie','Velocidad','Poder explosivo','Equilibrio corporal' ,'Coordinacion','Salto','Fuerza fisica','Portero','Atrapa el balon','Despeje','Respuesta de salvamento','Area de cobertura','Evaluacion general']
```

Queria saber alguna solución para poder obtener los datos. Si necesitan el codigo fuente lo pasare por el comentario.

La base de datos esta en localhost que ya se configuro en el archivo MySQL.py

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21

Comment: Ahora corrijo gracias.

Comment: Que contiene `data_name`? Ya que parece que la longitud de esa variable no coincide con tu lista

Comment: Es un array

`data_name = ['Capacidad ofensiva','Posesion de la pelota','Regatear','Pase de tierra','Pase de aire','Disparo','Establecer bola'
    ,'radian','Cabecera','Habilidad defensiva','Agarra la pelota','Fuerza del pie','Velocidad','Poder explosivo','Equilibrio corporal'
,'Coordinacion','Salto','Fuerza fisica','Portero','Atrapa el balon','Despeje','Respuesta de salvamento','Area de cobertura','Evaluacion general']`

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar la información esencial a la misma, los comentarios no son lugar para ella.

Comment: Arreglado. 

Hice lo que dijo Christian en data_name tuve que ajustar la cantidad de arrays y solo deje 4 arrays y quedo así

`data_name = ['Capacidad ofensiva','Posesion de la pelota','Regatear','Pase de tierra']`
En GetInfo.py cambie la siguiente linea:
`abilities = abilities[4:-3].replace(',[','').split("]")`